# as3 array of objects - movement with constant speed

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

Ok, so I have some experience with as3 and some of the basics. But this problem has been stumping me for so long. I tried to do a workaround based on what I currently know about as3. But somehow either i get an error message or it just doesn't do anything at all. Here is the code that i'm trying to solve.

```
    var zombieCount:Array = new Array();

    var helltime:Timer = new Timer(1500);
    helltime.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, spawnzombies)



    helltime.start();
    function spawnzombies(happened:TimerEvent){
        var zombie1:Zombie = new Zombie();
        zombieCount.push(zombie1);
        stage.addChild(zombieCount[zombieCount.length - 1]);
        zombie1.x = 135 + (330*Math.random())
        zombie1.y = -29


        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move_zombie)

        function move_zombie(happened:Event){
            for(var i:int; i < zombieCount.length; i++){
                zombieCount[i].y = zombieCount[i].y + 1;
                if(zombieCount[i].hitTestObject(border)){
                    stage.removeChild(zombieCount[i]);
                    zombieCount.shift();
                    trace(zombieCount.length);
                }

            }



        }
    }
```

Comment: Change `var i:int` to `var i:int = 0` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Also, which error are you getting?

Comment: Indeed, please edit your question to go into more detail about the desired result, and the current result (including the specific error(s) you're receiving).  There are some obvious things that I covered in my answer, but to get a full answer, you need to provide those details

Comment: @Pikamander2 - while for readability they should change it to `var i:int=0`, it's not really an issue as `0` is the default value for an `int` and functionally it will make no difference.  If it was declared as a `Number` it would be a different story though as number defaults to `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this may not be inclusive of everything wrong, here are at least a few of the issues I see.

1. Inline function issue:

   Inside your timer tick handler (`spawnZombies`), you create an inline function called `move_zombie` and then add an enter frame handler that calls that function.

   The issue here, is that every tick of the timer, will then create a whole new copy of that function, and add ANOTHER enter frame handler. This will create huge problems after a few timer ticks.

   Break that `move_zombie` function OUT OF the `spawn` function:

   eg:

   ```
   helltime.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, spawnzombies)
   helltime.start();

   stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move_zombie);

   function move_zombie(......

   function spawnzombies(.....
   ```
2. Iteration issue:

   In your for loop:

   ```
       for(var i:int; i < zombieCount.length; i++){
           zombieCount[i].y = zombieCount[i].y + 1;
           if(zombieCount[i].hitTestObject(border)){
               stage.removeChild(zombieCount[i]);
               zombieCount.shift();
               trace(zombieCount.length);
           }
       }
   ```

   You are not initializing your `i` value. While this will default it to `0`, it's still a good idea for readability to initialize it.

   So your iterating forward from 0 to the end of the array.  However, if your hit test succeeds, you then use the `shift` method of the array.  This removes the *first* item of the array (irrespective of what value `i` is at the time). This will remove the wrong item, plus mess up what `zombieCount[i]` refers to (because the amount of items has now changed after doing shift, so the next iteration `zombieCount[i]` will be a reference to same item as the previous iteration).

   Instead of what you're currently doing, use the `splice` method to remove, and iterate backwards so your index doesn't get out of whack.

   ```
   for(var i:int=zombieCount.length-1;i >=0;i--){
       zombieCount[i].y += 1; //move it down 1 pixel
       if(zombieCount[i].hitTestObject(border)){
           stage.removeChild(zombieCount[i]);
           zombieCount.splice(i,1); //remove the item at the current index (do this instead of shift)
           trace(zombieCount.length);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this was actually useful. Now i wouldn't have to worry about it doing crazy stuff like the zombie waiting and then speeding up while the other one waits. it helps a lot.